# Fedora - Can't install/update VLC

Tags: fedora, vlc, yum, fedora-21

Initially, I was trying to update VLC. I ended up uninstalling it to reinstall it.

Typing `yum install vlc` outputs :

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libfreerdp-gdi.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libliveMedia.so.17()(64bit)
           Available: live555-2013.11.26-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               libliveMedia.so.17()(64bit)
           Installed: live555-2014.10.21-1.fc21.x86_64 (@rpmfusion-free)
              ~libliveMedia.so.36()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libfreerdp-codec.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libfreerdp-core.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgcrypt.so.11()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libUsageEnvironment.so.1()(64bit)
           Available: live555-2013.11.26-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               libUsageEnvironment.so.1()(64bit)
           Installed: live555-2014.10.21-1.fc21.x86_64 (@rpmfusion-free)
              ~libUsageEnvironment.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libfreerdp-rail.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgroupsock.so.1()(64bit)
           Available: live555-2013.11.26-1.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               libgroupsock.so.1()(64bit)
           Installed: live555-2014.10.21-1.fc21.x86_64 (@rpmfusion-free)
              ~libgroupsock.so.4()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libfreerdp-utils.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libprojectM.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libfreerdp-kbd.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libfreerdp-channels.so.1.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libdvbpsi.so.7()(64bit)
           Available: libdvbpsi-0.2.2-3.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
               libdvbpsi.so.7()(64bit)
           Installed: libdvbpsi-1.2.0-3.fc21.x86_64 (@rpmfusion-free-updates)
              ~libdvbpsi.so.9()(64bit)
           Available: libdvbpsi-1.2.0-1.fc21.x86_64 (rpmfusion-free)
              ~libdvbpsi.so.9()(64bit)
Error: Package: 1:vlc-core-2.2.2-4.el7.nux.x86_64 (nux-dextop)
           Requires: libgcrypt.so.11(GCRYPT_1.2)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Here is the output of `uaname -a` :

```
Linux happydev 4.1.13-100.fc21.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 10 13:13:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I am willing to move forward, but I am not sure what to do, nor what to DuckDuckGo for. Any suggestion is most welcome !

**EDIT**

Most probably, the reason is that Fedora 21 is no longer maintaining its dependency to VLC. I am upgrading to Fedora 23 and will post the outcome here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, upgrading the from Fedora 21 to Fedora 23 solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

To make your answer more complete, there are few things wrong:

- Fedora 21 is EOL and therefore there are no more packages in the mirrors. Updating to Fedora 23 is very advisable.
- You are using `.el7` (RHEL7/CentOS7) packages, which might not be compatible with what you get from Fedora repositories. You should check the source of these packages and update your software sources in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` not to use CentOS repository, but Fedora one.